# How to opening an xls workbook on a url

Tags: android, jxl

I am fairly new to Android app development and have had some success in writing usable apps for my line of work. The below code is what I have tried to open an xls workbook which is located on a server. It compiles without error but does not seem to find/open the workbook. I have successfully opened and used the workbook from the ASSETS folder, so I am comfortable with that part. I just need to move the workbook to a server as it will be more efficient.

```
public void makeSite() throws IOException, BiffException {

    double latitude;
    double longitude;


    try {


        URL url = new URL("http://www.abc.....");
        InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();


        Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputStream);
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);



        for (int Row = 1; Row < 4998; Row++) {


            Cell siteNameCell = sheet.getCell(0, Row);
            Cell latitudeCell = sheet.getCell(1, Row);
            Cell longitudeCell = sheet.getCell(2, Row);
            Cell siteDownCell = sheet.getCell(3, Row);
            Cell siteChurnCell = sheet.getCell(4,Row);
            Cell siteRevCell = sheet.getCell(7,Row);

            latitude = Double.parseDouble(latitudeCell.getContents());
            longitude = Double.parseDouble(longitudeCell.getContents());
            siteName = siteNameCell.getContents();
            siteDown = Boolean.parseBoolean(siteDownCell.getContents());
            siteChurn = siteChurnCell.getContents();
            siteRev = siteRevCell.getContents();

            towerLatLong = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);


            if (siteDown == true) {
                siteDown(towerLatLong, siteName);

            } else {
                positionSite(towerLatLong, siteName,siteChurn,siteRev);

            }

        }

    } catch(Exception e){
        toast = Toast.makeText(this, "caught :" + e.getMessage(), toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
```

Comment: You should upload your full code for better insight

Comment: Updated with more code.

Comment: Is the URL that you supplied to url object valid? If no then that is the required issue in your code because of which the problem arises

Comment: the URL which is in my code here is not valid, it was for demonstration. The actual URL that I am using is valid and has a public IP address.

Comment: Just to confirm you did something like this...`URL url = new URL("www.abc.com/YourXLS.xls);` Did you?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: And **YourXLS.xls** is present on that link already beforehand?

Comment: If yes then you need to use Async Task or volley to establish the communication with server and I am quite sure this link would work: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/08/android-read-excel-file-from-website.html

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I will attempt it in that way. Is it possible to open the workbook whilst on the server as opposed to downloading it? The info is basically lats and longs for POI's that are plotted on a Google Map for me.

Comment: If you have gone through the code which I provided you then you can see that the code is just fetching the data from xls file not downloading it. Please have a look and then tell me. If you are satisfied with the comment,  flag the comment so it will help others

Comment: I will do so. There are parts of the sample provided with which I am not familiar with so I will have to read,research and learn something new. I will definitely revert once I have got it to work. Thank you